# Is US2463439 still active?

Tags: patent-lifetime

Sandwich Grill

I want to know if the patent of this product is still active, or is it available?

[US2463439](https://www.google.com/patents/US2463439)

Answer (score 1):

That patent was issued on March 1st, 1949. Back then, patents expired 17 years after the issue date. Thus the patent expired on March 1st, 1966.